# How does static work in this sample program?

Tags: java, static

```java
 import java.util.*;
 import net.rim.vm.*;

 public class AddressBook {

   static Vector addresses;
   static PersistentObject persist;


   static {
     // Hash of "net.rim.sample.AddressBook".
     long KEY =  0xa3b3159378f59a29L;
     persist = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject( KEY );
     if( persist.getContents() == null ) {
        persist.setContents( new Vector() );
        persist.commit();
     }
        addresses = (Vector)persist.getContents();
     }
   }

   void add( Address a ) {
     addresses.addElement( a );
     persist.commit();
   }
 }
```

[Source](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html)

Comment: It is an initialization block.

Comment: What are looking for ? a mere understanding ?

Comment: method `add` also needs to be static. The `[Source][1]` piece is not part of the code, right?

Answer (score 1):

This `static {....}` is called as static blocks. Those are used to initialize your static members. When class is loaded/intialized, static block is executed.

In your example, you are initializing address and vector using static block.

Answer (score 1):

1. This class is loaded
2. The static instance variables are initialized

   `static Vector addresses;`

   `static PersistentObject persist;`
3. Then the [static block](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/understanding-static-blocks/) is executed.

   `static{....}`

Answer (score 1):

A static block initializer is executed when the class is first loaded by the `ClassLoader`. This happens the first time an object of that class is instantiated, or the first time a static member of that class is accessed.

A static block initializer can be tought of as a *constructor* for instance fields. A constructor initializes instance variables with proper values, where the static block initializer assigns proper values to `static` variables.

Static blocks are useful when you want to initialize your static fields by executing code, like function invocation and loops, which cannot be place in a simple assignment statement.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [Static Initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), assuming you have only one class loader it will make sure that that code will be executed just once (or N times for N class loaders).

Static initializers are usually used to initialize fields for [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) objects.

Answer (score 0):

The static block will be executed when this class's (AddressBook) is first loaded in to the JVM.
Your variables will be available for use after the program is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

These static variables can be used without creating the objects for the class

static Vector addresses;
     static PersistentObject persist;

And if we use something like static{---}. It is called as Static Initializers. It is initialized before creating the objects

Answer (score 0):

The static variables are initialized firstly, then the static block

Comment: What dou you mean by 'the static block' is 'initialized'?